See Azure monitor in Azure Devops
We have multiple workbooks that we would like to be able to view in the Azure DevOps Dashboard. Since iframes do not work, is there something we can do to have a widget that allows us to either view the workbooks or specific metrics/queries from Azure?



There is an extension "Azure Application Insights Widgets" that provides the dashboard widgets to show Application Insights charts and metrics.
You can try to install use this extension in your Azure DevOps organization/collection.

